# How can I config workspace in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, workspace

I'm trying to activate workspace tool for my local project. I want to apply CSS changes on my codes when I edit them into browser.

I've added my folder, perfix url and path of my project to the Chrome like this:

[image]

But still there isn't any change in my codes when I change it into browser, What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to map a local workspace to a server path, using my example:

1. Click "Add folder" in the Workspace settings, and navigate to your working directory. Click "Allow" in the bar at the top to grant Chrome permissions.

[image: Permissions]

2. Add a mapping between your server and the path

[image: Mapping workspace]

3. Load the URL and navigate to the Sources tab. Open your file and start editing. 
   If you save with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Mac) / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Windows / Linux), the changes will be persisted in the workspace.

   [image: Editing a file]

You can read more information from the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en), which shows how to add it directly from the Sources panel. Read the Limitations section, in case you are trying to do something that isn't supported.