# Google DevTools: when i reload it reopen my js and css file

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use google DevTools as my IDE, and when i save a file and refresh the page it just reopen my css and javascript file.

In the opened file i can't save local so i have to get back to the local file again.

Any help?

//dnorhoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Workspaces feature of Chrome DevTools to add your local workspace, and optionally map it to a server path. See my answer to [How can I config workspace in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501361/how-can-i-config-workspace-in-chrome/37502031#37502031) for an example, or check out the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces).

When you load your web application in Chrome after configuring the workspace, all your changes made within the Sources tab will be persisted, and reloading the page will show the up-to-date version.