# how to save js file changes loaded in current debug instance in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, editor, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working with html/js/css on my local filesystem. I was running the app locally and I was able to make changes to the js file in chrome dev tools. The tab for the js file shows a "*" indicating that changes have been made. However, if I right-click and select Save then nothing happens. The ctrl-s shortcut does not work either. I selected "Add Folder to Workspace" from the context menu which allows me to use Chrome as a text editor for files on the filesystem but I'm still not able to save edits to files that have been opened in the debugger from that folder for the current app instance.  Can you please advise the steps I need to do to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the app directory to a [Workspace](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en), in order to save and persist changes. It looks like you tried to do the same thing as what I am about to say, but maybe something was missed. Here is a working example I just created:

You can see that I tried to save the local `script.js` file and it failed.

1. Right-click on the app directory, click "Add Folder to Workspace".

[image: Workspace 1]

2. Select your directory.
3. Click 'Allow' to the permission bar that appears at the top of the window
4. Close the existing files open in Sources, collapse the `top` node and expand the workspace directory.
5. Open your script and try editing and saving. It should persist this time.

[image: Workspace 2]

If you are running a local web server to serve your files, you need to map the server path to the workspace directory. Check out [Stage persisted changes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en#stage-persisted-changes) for details, or follow [my instructions on creating mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501361/how-can-i-config-workspace-in-chrome/37502031#37502031) from the main DevTools settings panel.